# convert row as columns in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table and it look like this

```
RegNo------------Subject-----------------Eligibility
112109-----------CMIS 1113---------------Eligible
112109-----------ELTN 1113---------------Not Eligible
112109-----------IMGT 1113---------------Eligible
112108-----------CMIS 1113---------------Eligible
112108-----------ELTN 1113---------------Not Eligible
112108-----------IMGT 1113---------------Not Eligible
112107-----------CMIS 1113---------------Eligible
```

I want to convert above table as follows

```
RegNo------------CMIS 1113-----------------ELTN 1113--------------IMGT 1113
112109-----------Eligible------------------Not Eligible-----------Eligible
112108-----------Eligible------------------Not Eligible-----------Not Eligible
112107-----------Eligible------------------Null-------------------Null
```

I do not know whether this is possible or not.So it would be very much grateful if anyone can help me.Thank you

Comment: you can't to get data result with variable column count, however it possible if set of subject values is predefined...

Comment: Ok.if then how to do it?

Comment: How many of `Subject` could be possible in this case is it limited to only few ?

Comment: subquery for each column, for example :)

Answer (score 2):

For a known set of values from row which needs to be shown as columns it could be done using the following technique.

```
SELECT
  RegNo,
  max(if(Subject = 'CMIS 1113', Eligibility, NULL)) as `CMIS 1113`,
  max(if(Subject = 'ELTN 1113', Eligibility, NULL)) as `ELTN 1113`,
  max(if(Subject = 'IMGT 1113', Eligibility, NULL)) as `IMGT 1113`
from table_name 
group by RegNo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't to get data result with variable column count.
However it possible if set of subject values is predefined...
You can build your query like here:

```
$subjects = array(
  'CMIS 1113',
  'ELTN 1113',
  'IMGT 1113'
);

$joins = array();
$fields = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($subjects); $i++) {
  $joins[] = "LEFT JOIN Table t{$i} ON t0.ReqNo=t{$i}.ReqNo AND Subject = '{$subjects[$i]}'";
  $fields[] = "t{$i}.Eligibility as `{$subjects[$i]}`";
}
$joins = implode(' ', $joins);
$fields = implode(',', $fields);

$sql = "SELECT t.ReqNo, $fields
From table t
$joins
Group by t.ReqNo
";
```

Result query for will be like:

```
SELECT t.ReqNo, t0.Eligibility as `CMIS 1113` /*similar fields*/
From table t
LEFT JOIN table t0 ON t.ReqNo = t0.ReqNo AND t0.Subject = 'CMIS 1113'
/*similar joins*/
Group by t.ReqNo
```

Comment: Is this a MySql query?

Comment: Interesting alternative to the pure dynamic sql

Comment: it's building MySQL query using PHP.

Comment: @Mihai, but it still heavier :)